remove event subscriptions from system topics
my powershell code is so slow to delete all the event subscriptins from the system topic.
# Get all event subscription names associated with the system topic
$subscriptions = az eventgrid system-topic event-subscription list --system-topic-name $systemTopicName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --query "[].name" -o tsv

# Iterate through each subscription and delete it
foreach ($sub in $subscriptions) {
    Write-Host "Deleting event subscription: $sub"
    az eventgrid system-topic event-subscription delete --system-topic-name $systemTopicName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $sub --yes
}

Is there any faster way to remove all the event subscriptions?

ForEach-Object -Parallel is available from Powershell v7.0 and can be used to parallelize work.
Try something like this (not tested):
# Get all event subscription names associated with the system topic
$subscriptions = az eventgrid system-topic event-subscription list --system-topic-name $systemTopicName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --query "[].name" -o tsv

# Iterate through each subscription and delete it
$subscriptions | Foreach-Object -Parallel {
    Write-Host "Deleting event subscription: $_"

    az eventgrid system-topic event-subscription delete --system-topic-name $systemTopicName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --name $_ --yes
} -ThrottleLimit 5

Please note that:

The order of execution is not guaranteed
The -ThrottleLimit parameter limits the number of script blocks running in parallel at a given time, and its default value is 5.

See ForEach-Object for more details and examples.

i get this error ForEach-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

@Greencolor which version of Powershell are you using? You can check it with $PSVersionTable

Also, use --name $_ instead of --name $sub.

$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision

5      1      22621  3672

I did change that paramter too but did not work. in addtion I also defined param($sub) inside the foreach but did not work

As mentioned in my answer, that functionality is available from Powershell v7. Your version is very, very old - I suggest you upgrade it very soon.

And don't forget to upgrade Azure CLI as well :-)
